# Sharing a function scoped pytest fixture among a class tests

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a `function` fixture that is called for each test:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_app():
    yield app...

def test_app(my_app):
   ...

def test_other_app(my_app):
   ...
```

This works fine so far. But now, I have a few other tests for whom I want to share across them a single `my_app` instance . So, I created a new `shared_app` fixture with class scope that ideally would take a single `my_app` instance and share it at the class level like in the following code:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def shared_app(my_app):
    yield my_app

class InterestingTest(object):
    def test_shared_app(shared_app):
       ...

    def test_other_shared_app(shared_app):
       ...
```

But this results in the following **error**: `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'shared_app' with a 'class' scoped request object, involved factories`

I also tried moving the fixture to the class, e.g.:

```py
class InterestingTest(object):
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def shared_app(my_app):
        self.my_app = my_app
        yield

    def test_shared_app():
       ...

    def test_other_shared_app():
       ...
```

and it gives the same error. And similarly, removing `scope='class'`, then the fixture doesn't ever seem to be called. Adding `shared_app` explicitly to the tests, then `shared_app` is not actually shared, but is created for each test.

So, how can I share a `function` fixture among a few tests in a class?

Comment: Set scope to "module" and it will run once per a test module.

Comment: How is that going to solve the issue? I need the fixture to run per each function for some tests and once for each class for other tests.

Comment: Sry, I missunderstood you. Your working example hasn't got any parameter, why you added one later in `scope="class"` example?

Comment: I added some text, hopefully that explains the reasoning. Otherwise, I'm no sure I understood what you asked.

Comment: `def my_app():` vs `def shared_app(my_app):`... Are you making fixture from fixture or it's just a typo?

Comment: I am making a new fixture from the existing one. The idea is to make the new fixture with a class scope since the existing one has a function scope.

Comment: That's not going to work unless you make another fixture unrelated to the existing one. If you want a fixture to be called for every test function, then it can't be run once on a class level.

Comment: Hmm, ok. That's too bad. I can't just copy the `function` fixture code to make a duplicate one with a class scope because I'm using a fixture from a plugin.

Comment: You should accept the provided [correct] answer

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, what you are trying to do is to share the very same fixture function `my_app` across multiple test files. I suggest you put this function in `conftest.py` in the main test directory (along other test files). Then:

**conftest.py:**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def my_app():
    yield app...
```

**test_*.py:**

```
def test_app(my_app):
   ...

def test_other_app(my_app):
   ...
```

should work.

[More on special file `conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. In hindsight, I'm able to state the problem more clearly; I want a fixture that is both function scoped (for the `test_app` and `test_other_app` tests) and a class or module scoped (`InterestingTest`). But this is currently impossible in pytest. 

Your suggestion would not work because then each class test would create a new fixture and it won't be shared.

Comment: I see. Yes, it would not be shared.